# Unreliable DNS resolving for external domains using Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I am getting bad / unreliable DNS performance of the DNS server running on my domain controller. It's for external domains. This results (among other things) in a very bad browsing experience both on the server and on the clients.

To isolate the problem down to DNS only I resolved domains using nslookup, which gives the following result for each new domain I try:

```
 > pb.nl    
 Server: localhost     
 Address: 127.0.0.1     
 DNS request timed out.    
     timeout was 2 seconds.    
 *** Request to localhost timed-out
```

A subsequent second attempt in the same session in most cases does work:

```
> pb.nl
Server: localhost 
Address: 127.0.0.1
Non-authorative answer: 
Name: pb.nl 
Address: 95.211.59.50
```

When I try to resolve with a the Google DNS server directly (the first forwarder configured) using  'nslookup - 8.8.8.8' it instantly resolves every domain. Also when I configure 8.8.8.8 as the DNS server for a client it works as expected (quick).

From hours of searching and trial and error I got the following solutions, none of them worked (and reverted each step after I tried without succes):

1. Change the forwarders to other DNS servers than 8.8.8.8, 208.67.222.222 and 4.2.2.1, didn't work and also the fact that 'nslookup - 8.8.8.8' worked quickly and that was the first forwarder rules out that the forwarders were wrongly configured
2. I disabled EDNS with: 'dnscmd /config /enableednsprobes 0' but this also should not be relevant for our situation where we only use the internal Windows Firewall and have tried behind 2 different routers on 2 different internet connections.
3. I removed the primary DNS name on the IP6 properties of the NIC and set to automatically
4. I disabled IP6 on the NIC
5. Added the MaxCAcheTtl record (http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2009/01/29/cannot-resolve-names-in-certain-top-level-domains-like-co-uk.aspx)

Any help on this would be greatly appericiated.

For diagnosis / additional information:

When I use Wireshark I see that on the first request the correct IP is received and on the second request it retrieves it from the cache of the windows DNS server.

---

```
ipconfig /all


Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Atreyu
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : AMteam.local
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : AMteam.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TeamViewer VPN Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-69-5A-4D-F1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : HP Network Team #1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-25-B3-A1-15-80
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::58d4:bed7:1ced:b827%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.57.51(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.57.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 385885619
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-AD-B4-23-00-25-B3-A1-15-81
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A590BBD1-B0A8-4DB6-9A59-8A210FCE2964}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{695A4DF1-6C55-4717-942D-0BD5BA32DD27}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

---

```
nslookup 192.168.57.51 (server it self)
*** localhost can't find 192.168.57.51: Non existent domain
```

Comment: What's between this server and the Internet? firewalls? switches? routers?

Comment: Between this server is now a DrayTek 2930n, before it was a Cisco 891. Both giving the same issues. Both are configured as Dual Wan, problem persists on both connections.

Comment: Wondering if those edge devices are mangling the replies, or perhaps you're getting some asymmetry here. Does the problem persist using root hints instead of forwarders?

Comment: I removed all forwarders, refreshed the root hints lists, then tried to resolve DNS on the server, everything times out, no results.

Comment: And AMteam.local lookups are fine?

Comment: Can you post up a screen of wireshark with a full capture of a DNS request/response from the server?

Comment: Yes AMteam.local works quick and good, will get the Wireshark screenshot asap.

Comment: We had a similar problem with the DNS our Windows Server 2012. It turned out the DNS still had a forwarder set up to another DNS server on our local network which had since been retired. I removed that forwarder and it started working immediately. Thanks to your comment I realised that I should check the forwarders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. The server has 2 network ports which worked together as a 'Teamed' connection. Once we disabled the teaming and one of the NICs all worked like a charm.